# Is it necessary to translate WordPress key terms when localizing a plugin

Tags: plugins, localization

In translating a plugin, how should "WordPress" key terms be handled? For instance, should the following need translations or should they be left as is:

- Taxonomy
- Custom Post Type
- Taxonomy Term
- Plugin

Since these terms all have very specific meanings and are documented within the Codex using these English words, would it make more sense to just leave them in English as opposed to translating them? I almost think of these words as proper nouns that would not be changed when translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terms are not proper nouns and are translated in localized versions of WP Core.

Therefore, they should also be translated in plugins.

Ideally, you could use them without a textdomain and WP would load it's own translation.

Comment: I didn't even think to look what WP Core did with it. I'm gonna start a new question about this now...