# What does "_x( " and "__(" mean in Custom Post Type Arguments

Tags: custom-post-types

Can someone let me know what does "*x(" and "*_(" mean in Custom Post Type? For example at following code:

```
'name'          => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Product' ),
```

why we use the *x for 'name' and _* for the 'add_new_item'? Can you please let me know what are the differences between them?

Comment: See [Internationalization (I18n)](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Comment: The codex is your friend: see [_x](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x), and [__](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)

Comment: Note, your examples don’t use a text domain, so they don’t work anyway.

Comment: @toscho technically, domains are optional (defaults to 'default')

Comment: @vancoder No, if the string is not part of the core code, the translation will not work. For custom strings the text domain is _required_. See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77335/73

Comment: @toscho Right. The codex for the functions is misleading. Both state that domain is optional.

Comment: Yeah, _no error message_ and _it works_ are two very different events. :)